# Wakanda Enterprise Studio launches as a background process

Tags: background, enterprise, wakanda, windowless

Windows 10 14393.105
16GB RAM
64bit OS
Wakanda Ent Studio 11.197492 - fresh install
All other Wakanda's uninstalled
Norton 360 - auto protect - off

When I launch Wak Ent Studio, it loads and runs as a background process, and no window displays.

It was working two days ago.

I uninstalled all Wakanda's, and reinstalled Wak Ent, latest version.

How do I fix this so that I can use Wak End Studio?

Comment: Have you tried to kill the studio process and then launch Wakanda studio ?

Comment: Do your internet connection is stable? Sometimes the Studio takes minutes to start because of an unstable internet connection (3G connection with low signal for instance. If there is no internet connection at all the Studio starts quickly)

Comment: Yes I killed the WES process and then relaunched. Same result - WES is launching as a background process.

Comment: My internet connect is surely not perfect, but it is up 99+% of the time. It's 1mbs up and 1MBs down most of the time. I just retested with no connection and then with a connection. Both times WES launches as a background application.

Comment: Did you try to switch Windows 10 background app feature ? http://superuser.com/a/960213
http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7225-background-apps-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to reinstall the entire machine, from scratch.

I do not know what was causing the problem, and I had to make progress.

It works now, after a fresh machine install.